# Added something to the database but not reflecting in wordpress page

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

there is this wordpress plugin, the main functions of that plugin is to take data from the user and write that data to the database, it also Update data and Delete data, then display the changes to the page that the plugin provides.

Now, I want to add thousands of items, but I cannot manually add each items using the plug-ins interface because that would take so long, so what I did is I head over to phpmyadmin locate the tables of the plug-in and I use sql Insert to add data to the database, after trial and error, I SUCCESSFULLY inserted all of the data in all of the tables that is relevant to the plug-in, no errors!.. I analyzed it carefully. but when I head over to the page, and to the live site, the items that I inserted is not showing up. not even one. the items that is only showing is the items that I added using the plug-ins interface, what should I do?

Comment: Hard to say. I'd guess either there's other tables involved you're not adding the right data to, or that you're editing the wrong database somehow (maybe you've got a backup set of tables, or a dev/prod split). Or there's a cache in place that using the UI clears.

Answer (score 1):

Good job by the way, but make sure that
1. You're inserting data to the correct schematic & table.
2. You didn't insert a null or invalid data (like floats in int data type)
3. try refreshing the page if that's a cache problem, clear the cache and try again

Comment: I am just inserting data in un-orderd manner, how do I access the correct schematic?

Comment: can you give me some details about the plugin

Comment: Plugin Name: Geo Directory, it has 7 tables in the database, I checked each table and I added the appropriate data on each table

Comment: I didn't actually used this plugin but you can find more help on https://wpgeodirectory.com/support/topic/schema/